# The question is around the "Gambling" zone with addition of math

Tags: java

after adding two int variables to (a) and (b),
I have to gamble (a) times values between 10 to 100 and 
calculate which square root of these gambled numbers is the closest to (b).

For example a=3 and b=2

output:
Gambled 16,25,49.
The number 16 was chosen since it's square root (4) is the closest to b=2.

I am stuck in the part of calculation of the square root, and saving the closest value to b each time the loop runs, i'm not allowed to use arrays,
this is the third question of my first task and i'd appreciate any experienced ideas to be shared ^^.
(MyConsole is a replacement for the scan command)

```
    int a = MyConsole.readInt("Enter value a:");
    int b = MyConsole.readInt("Enter value b:");


        for(int i = 0; i<a; a--){
                int gambler = ((int)(Math.random() *91)+10);
                double Root = Math.sqrt(gambler);
                double Distance= Root-b;

            {
                System.out.println();
```

Comment: so store the  first number you gamble and see if the next is closer or not if it is store that and so on  and return the closest

Comment: I think you also want to increment the counter `a`, not decrement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I found the minimum. You can also use arrays to store all the gambling values if you want for future use. I also used `Scanner` but you can use your `MyConsole` I'm just not familiar with it. I hope it helps. דש מישראל

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value a:");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter value b:");
    int b = scanner.nextInt();

    double min = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        int gambler = ((int) (Math.random() * 91) + 10);
        double root = Math.sqrt(gambler);
        double distance = Math.abs(root - b);
        if (min > distance)
            min = distance;
    }

    System.out.println("minimum value is: " + min);
}
```

Comment: its not quite equivalent to the required instructions but i get your idea

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka post your instructions so we can know what is not working properly